# How to get code completion on PHP class variables in NetBeans 7.0?

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

Netbeans 7.0 has nice code completion for PHP variables:

[image]

How can I get it to give me code completion for internal class variables as well?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inline "var" hints only work for single variables.

If `dummyItems` is a member of your class, specify its type in the declaration, ie

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var DatapodItems
     */
    private $dummyItems;
```

Comment: be sure to include TWO stars on the first line which is not included by default in netbeans if you just type "/*" RETURN.